# Is this the fundamental solution?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, boundary-value-problem, fundamental-solution

Let

$$Tu=\bigg(t\Psi +x \partial_x\bigg)u=0$$

where $\Psi=\partial_{tt}.$

Define a kernel which solves this equation by

$$ u(t,x)=\exp\bigg(\frac{t}{\log x} \bigg) $$

for all $t>0$ and $u,x\in(0,1)$. Consider a square domain with boundary $\Omega \in \Bbb R^2$ s.t. $\Omega=[0,1]^2.$ Define the initial condition

$$ \lim_{t \to 0} u(t,x):=\psi(x)$$

where the limit is taken in the sense of distributions. Also define the condition

$$ u(t,x)=0 \space\space\space x \in \partial \Omega  $$

I believe I've set up the conditions correctly.

> Is $u(t,x)$ the fundamental solution for $Tu=0?$

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. What does $x\in(0,1)$ combined with $x\in\Omega$ even mean? Because $x\in\Bbb{R}$ can't exist on $\partial \Omega$, and $x\in\Bbb{R}^2$ makes $\log x$ and the differential equation nonsensical.

Comment: @NinadMunshi $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ not all of $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: You missed the point of my question completely. Do you understand mine and others' confusion? The problem is ill posed as phrased. If I was sure of what you really meant I would have gladly corrected it for you instead of posting criticisms with no fixes.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I guess I don't understand why it's ill posed. with $\psi(x)$ this is the distribution of the energy or whatever you wanna call it at $t=0$ and at $t=0$ this distribution is on the boundary of $\Omega.$